# How to define a variable that can be used everywhere?

Tags: c#

How do I define a variable that I can use everywhere in my program in C#.

Comment: Ehh? Your question title doesn't match the question body, I don't know what a "private void" is, and what problem are you trying to solve? You're essentially asking to make a global variable (based on the question body), which is generally not a good idea.

Comment: @in-silico: Yes, I mean a global variable.

Comment: @Iman Hejazi: What problem are you trying to solve that makes you think global variables are an acceptable solution? It's almost never a good idea because it makes code harder to maintain and debug.

Comment: @In silico: I defined an string in a `private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)` and I want to use its value in `private void button1_Click_1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)` But system cant recognize that string in second one.

Comment: I second the notion that globals are not often a very good idea.  User beware!

Comment: @Iman Hejazi Assuming those event handlers are in the same class (e.g. the same Form), make the variable a field or property of the Form.

Comment: My advice to learn the language first
After that you should read something about windows forms
After you do all that if you have a problem and want to solve you come to here and ask about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the Settings page in the project properties. You can then use:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.(Whatever variable you want to access)
```

Keep in mind that this is more used for program settings, but it can work in a pinch.

Answer (score 1):

Global read-only variable is normally done with a static public property

```
class Glo
{
    private int _n;
    public int n
    {
        get
        {
            return _n;
        }
    }
}
```

At least, half the problems that globals normally create would go away. Assignment to _n is done somehow within the Glo class.

Answer (score 1):

If `checkBox1_CheckedChanged` and `button1_Click_1` are both in the same class (IOW they are both on the same control/window), then you can just declare a module (class) level variable:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string _myString = null;

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        _myString = "some value";
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //you can now use _myString in this function
    }
}
```

While your question talks about using a global variable, according to your follow up comment it isn't actually what you need - you simply need a variable that is visible between functions in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

public class Globals
{
  public static int SomeVar;
}

But this is usually a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Web.Config or App.Config -- as long as you simply really only want to *use* the value anywhere. e.g.

> ```
> <appSettings>
>     <add key="myValue" value="You can see me anywhere!"/>
> </appSettings>
> ```